# Azure Related Error - VS 2013 Professional - The 'CctProjectPackage' package did not load correctly

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, package

I am running Visual Studio Professional 2013 to create Azure Cloud websites using Azure 2.4.

This has been running fine without issues for months, and then all of a sudden on my home machine, I am getting the above error and all my Azure Cloud Service projects in all my existing solutions are listed as incompatible with my version of the software. If I try and create a new Azure Cloud Service project, it just outright fails.

```
<entry>
<record>641</record>
<time>2015/02/14 09:56:30.100</time>
<type>Warning</type>
<source>UserConnection</source>
<description>Newer version of resource during SetAttribute: VSS011053: A different version of resource &apos;VisualStudio.12;Environment.General&apos; exists on the server. Given version &apos;0&apos; while existing version is &apos;2373&apos;. (ActivityId: a432dc90-386f-4215-85d3-ad0f89dd8bd0)</description>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>642</record>
<time>2015/02/14 09:56:30.991</time>
<type>Warning</type>
<source>UserConnection</source>
<description>Newer version of resource during SetAttribute: VSS011053: A different version of resource &apos;VisualStudio.12;Environment.Startup&apos; exists on the server. Given version &apos;0&apos; while existing version is &apos;2374&apos;. (ActivityId: 27589d22-4ba2-416c-8950-f6998dc49a3c)</description>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>643</record>
<time>2015/02/14 09:56:34.756</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
<guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>644</record>
<time>2015/02/14 09:56:34.756</time>
<type>Warning</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Unexpected system error mode before loading package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
<guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>645</record>
<time>2015/02/14 09:56:34.756</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
<guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>646</record>
<time>2015/02/14 09:56:34.802</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
<guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>647</record>
<time>2015/02/14 10:56:16.398</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>ClientRights</source>
<description>Read client rights token for IdeUser User: &apos;john@doe.com&apos; (ActvityId: &apos;b5c38855-50e7-40c8-804c-f164a010b1a7&apos;) from &apos;C:\Users\ismithers\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Licenses\1_kdatcfot.crtok&apos;</description>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>648</record>
<time>2015/02/14 11:32:03.632</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
<guid>{3CF1DF15-44F2-4467-AB0E-1F90BA69A3E0}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>649</record>
<time>2015/02/14 11:32:03.632</time>
<type>Information</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Begin package load [CctProjectPackage]</description>
<guid>{3CF1DF15-44F2-4467-AB0E-1F90BA69A3E0}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>650</record>
<time>2015/02/14 11:32:03.632</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>CreateInstance failed for package [CctProjectPackage]</description>
<guid>{3CF1DF15-44F2-4467-AB0E-1F90BA69A3E0}</guid>
<hr>80131604</hr>
<errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>651</record>
<time>2015/02/14 11:32:03.632</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [CctProjectPackage]</description>
<guid>{3CF1DF15-44F2-4467-AB0E-1F90BA69A3E0}</guid>
<hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
<errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Visual Studio -> Help Menu -> About - Shows this error window:

"The 'CctProjectPackage' package did not load correctly."

File -> New -> Project -> Azure Cloud Service -> OK -> OK -> Shows a window with the message:

"'C:\etc\etc...\AzureProject.ccproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.ccproj) is not supported by this version of the application."

I have tried:

```
A full uninstall of Visual Studio 2013 Professional. Then reinstalled.
Removed all optional packages and reinstalled.
Repaired Visual Studio 2013 Professional and Azure Tools 2.4.
Tried various command line commands such as reinstalling the templates, manually registering the AzureDiagnostics.dll and resetting Visual Studio 2013 Professional.
Cleaned registry.
Installed to a new directory.
```

One thing which surprised me, was that when I installed a different version of Visual Studio 2013 (for example the Web Express version). Everyone worked. But, not in my Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Eagerly await your reply and assistance, many thanks.

Comment: To add some additional comments, I have tried /Resetsettings, /ResetSkipPkgs and /Safemode all of which have not resolved the issue - these were suggest by a MSDN rep.

Comment: I actually did attempt the steps in the answer by Jon Crowell however it did not resolve it for me. That being said i would suggest that for others as a first step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem after windows 10 updated. 
I was able to fix it by following these steps:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open the *Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ folder
3. Rename the ComponentModelCache folder
4. Restart Visual Studio.

Hope it helps... :)

Comment: @ncu Can you follow these steps and if it resolves your issue, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Going to accept this as the answer since it is far superior to 'reinstalling'. Thanks @hugocabral :)

Comment: So turns out after a Windows 10 Update, this happened to me again. I quickly came back to this post and tried the steps posted by @hugocabral and can verify that they worked for me. Would love to know what prompted this solution, as it feels very esoteric to me.

Answer (score 1):

So I resolved this by re-installing Windows 8.

That is about as a legitimate solution to this issue, as fixing a broken air-con by buying a new car, is. But in the end continuing to troubleshoot this was time prohibitive.

Comment: Same problem here, it started after updating to Azure SDK 2.6. Now the Azure node is unavailable in the Server Explorer and I also get the same error message when opening VS About. Just reinstalled my PC a couple of weeks ago, and I don't want to go through the hassle again. 

I already reinstalled the SDK and VS. Is there anybody from the MS Azure team who knows a proper solution?

Comment: @ncu I did attempt to post on the Azure forums, and Visual Studio forums and after being told by both to post on the other, I just threw the towel in. I'm very interested to hear what the actual issue ends up being though, if you make any headway.

Comment: I think the root cause of "cctProjectPackage" warning is installing the Azure SDK and VS update 4 separately. I finally did an Image restore on my PC, installed the Azure SDK 2.5 and then VS update 4 and the warning message was back. I uninstalled the Azure SDK and downloaded and installed VS_with_update4 from MSDN and the message went away. But still I don't see the Storage node under Azure in the Server Explorer, which was the first reason to update the SDK. I also had VS2015 installed, maybe this is also part of the problem but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @ncu I also had it where the error dialog no longer appeared, but upon checking the ActivityLog.xml file I could see the package was failing to load still. Also if I checked the Visual Studio -> Help -> About screen, I could not see the Azure Tools listed there.

Comment: Don't perform this step as it is unnecessary, instead follow the steps from @hugocabral's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved by repairing the install of Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio.

Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features (appwiz.cpl)

Select Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio from the list of installed programs, click change and repair. When if completes, reboot (if prompted) and the issue should be gone.